# How to replace the Python interpreter of an existing venv virtual environment in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

A couple days ago I created a `venv` virtual environment that uses the Python interpreter version 3.11.6. Now that a new Python version, 3.12.0, has been released, how can I replace the interpreter of my existing virtual environment by the new version? Or must I create a whole new virtual environment if I wish to use the newer interpreter version?

My IDE is Visual Studio Code 1.82.3. My operating system is Windows 10 Pro v. 22H2.

Comment: lib path inside venv is python version specific. Then, if you had any libraries that rely on native libraries, also those files are tied to a specific python version. So you need to re-create it.

Comment: with `pip` get a `requirements.txt` file of 3.11 venv, create a new venv for Python 3.12 and use ``requirements.txt` with `pip` to install all the modules in new venv

Comment: @rioV8: Thanks. Could you give more detailed instructions, please? How do I get a `requirements.txt` file with `pip`? How to I use this `requirements.txt` file to install all the modules in the new venv?

Comment: do a web search for `python pip requirements.txt`

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current project does not use additional installed modules, you can directly switch to the new version of the interpreter. If the current environment already uses third-party packages, you will also need to install the same modules for the new version of the interpreter environment.

You can use the `pip freeze > requirements.txt` command in the **old** environment to generate a **requirements.txt** file containing all packages in the current environment.

Then use the `pip install -r requirements.txt` command to install all packages in the file in the **new** environment.

Comment: Thanks. You wrote: "you can directly switch to the new version of the interpreter". Would you mind elaborating this? How can I directly switch to the new version of the interpreter?

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+P` --> `Python: Select Interpreter`

Comment: Does this replace the interpreter used by venv by a different one? I'm a little skeptic, because when I use the venv interpreter it says `.venv (Python 3.11.6)` on the upper right of the editor frame, but when I switch to the new version it simply says `Python 3.12.0`.

Comment: If you switch interpreters, your new chosen interpreter will of course be used. I don't understand what is your problem? What effect do you want?

Comment: Hi not sure if you already got what you need but I think you missed each other with the meaning. If you switch to the new Python 3.12.0 via Vscode and it only says "Python 3.12.0" you chose the main python interpreter without a virtual env. I'm currently search for the same thing if its possible to take over a virt env to a newer versions but I think you have to create a new one. And there the `pip freeze` and `pip install -r` are quite usefull.